# Extract exp(-coef) from coxph

Tags: r, cox-regression

Does anyone know how to extract the value stored in "exp(-coef)" (**negative!**) in the summary of a coxph model? My model is fitted like this:

```
mycoxfit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ therapy, data = mydata)
```

I can extract the exp(coef) by

```
coef(mycoxfit)
```

or

```
summary(mycoxfit)$coefficients[, 1]
```

But I am not able to read the values from the column "exp(-coef)" (the exp from the **negative** coef).

**The reason why I need this is**: If I want to get the HR for therapy = 1, this is just the exp(coef). But I also want the HR for therapy = 0 - this should be the "exp(-coef"), correct? Or is it the inverse of exp(coef), i.e. "1 - exp(coef)"?

Thank you!

Comment: `1/exp(coef)` ?

Comment: you can have a look at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/329380/68626) on cross validated ; also [this other one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/83892/68626)

Comment: Cath, thank you for your answer!